How do I do extensible state if only the extension needs to know its state?
I'm trying to write a game in haskell and i'd like to write it in a modular way. To simplify it, I have a GameState and functions that do GameState -> GameState.
type Dog = Int

data GameState = GameState {
   cat :: String,
   extensionState :: ExtState
}

data ExtState = ExtState {
    dogExt :: Dog
}

type ExtEffects = [GameState -> GameState]

-- (we can partially apply the lens so it becomes `GameState -> `GameState`
type StatefulEffect s = Lens' GameState s -> GameState -> GameState

doDog :: StatefulEffect Dog
doDog l gs = over l (+1) gs

-- maybe you could define the extension as something similar to this?
data Extension s = Extension {
    extState :: s,
    extEffect :: StatefulEffect s
}

In this example, the only thing that needs to access the Dog in ExtState is doDog. So doDog is essentially like an extension that has its own state which is stored in GameState. (In a real implementation, doDog would also act on parts of the GameState that are known by everyone).
It's workable like this, but I'd like to be able to do this without having to define each field manually in State, and adding the function to ExtEffects and giving it the lens (not shown here). Ideally, I could pass the enabled extensions into some sort of list (at compile time) and it would magically work out. The state also doesn't need to be stored as a field; anything works as long it's accessible by a lens on GameState.
I've tried using the extensible library to add rows to the record with row-polymorphism. It works, but it's just as much boilerplate as this pretty much. The lenses are the issue, since they all need to know the type of ExtState. And even if I got those to work, I have no idea how to reduce the boilerplate so you only need to 'enable' an extension in one place.

Looks like XY problem.

"Ideally, I could pass the enabled extensions into some sort of list (at compile time)" -- can you say carefully why listing fields in the record definition does not qualify as "some sort of list"?

@DanielWagner because doing it like this I would also need to list it in other places; i'd need to list its state in the record, give the function a lens that points to it, and also add the function somewhere. it's fine if the 'list' is the record definition, but i'd like to only need to list things in one place so it's easier to maintain and change.

@freestyle ok, ig it might be. what i want in general, is that i have a system that transforms a data structure (the game state). i'd like to add some sort of extension system to this, so that i can add more transformations without needing to change a bunch of things. some of these transformations will need to keep track of extra things in order to function, which should be tied into the main 'state' in some way. so that, e.g. if i try to restore an older game state, what they were keeping track of will also be restored.

@hello Does lens' Template Haskell machinery get you where you need to go, then?
